# 'event.srcElement.removeEventListener' doesn't work - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I can't to find way which will allow me to delete of onclick event at button (//here here here here here). I spent a lot of time looking for a solution to this problem and still did not find it. I hope someone will help me, thanks.

cart.component.ts

```js
getCartProducts(event: Event, cart: ICart) {
        for (let product of cart.Products)
        {
            event.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<tr><td>" + product.Name + "</td><td>" + product.Price + "</td></tr>");
        }
        event.srcElement.textContent = "Скрыть продукты";
        event.srcElement.attributes.getNamedItem("title").value = "Скрыть продукты";      
                 
        /* this doesn't work!! */ event.srcElement.removeEventListener("click", function (e) { CartsComponent.prototype.getCartProducts(event, cart) }, false);         
        /* but this works!! */ event.srcElement.addEventListener("click", function (e) { CartsComponent.prototype.hideCartProducts(event) }, false);
    }
    
     hideCartProducts(event: Event) {
        event.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<span>qwqeq</span>");        
    }
```

cart.component.html

```html
<table class='table table-striped' *ngIf='carts && carts.length'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Название</th>
                            <th>Описание</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let cart of carts">
                            <td>{{cart.Name}}</td>
                            <td>{{cart.Description}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button title="Показать продукты" class="btn btn-show" (click)="getCartProducts($event, cart)">Показать продукты</button> //here here here here here
                                <button title="Изменить" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editCart(cart.Id)">Изменить</button>
                                <button title="Удалить" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteCart(cart.Id)">Удалить</button>
                            </td>                          
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Guys, please will write your answer in more detail, because I do not understand what I should to do.

Comment: The second function passed to `removeEventListener` should be a reference to a function, not a funtion itself. You've to use named functions if you want to remove listeners.

Comment: @Teemu — Functions are only ever passed by reference. There is no need to give the function a name. (Do not confuse "having a name" with "being referenced by a variable"). It just needs to be the same function each time.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I know, poor wording in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `removeEventListener` must be the function you want to remove. It cannot be an identical function, it must be the **same** function.

```
var foo = function (e) { ... };
x.addEventListener("event_name", foo);
x.removeEventListener("event_name", foo);
```

Note how the value of the `foo` variable doesn't change, so the same function is passed to both add and remove event listener.

Comment: Okay, thank you, i understand your answer, BUT how can i do that in my case????? Exactly the answer i find.

Answer (score -1):

removeEventListener won't work with anonymous functions.
convert it to external functions.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp

Comment: Can you write in more detail? Because I do not understand how to do this.